# Problemas com a formatação do Double

Tags: c#, .net, formatação, conversão-de-tipo, globalização

Tenho um método que recebe valores do tipo `string` e realiza a conversão para outros tipos, o meu problema é que ao converter uma informação para `double` ela troca o seu valor preciso que isso não aconteça. Por exemplo, recebo "19.30". uso o método abaixo para converter e acabo ficando com o valor "1930,00", ou coisa parecida.

Recebo "19.30" na variável x.

```
val = Convert.ToDouble(x);
```

O valor de val fica por exemplo: "19300,0" mas preciso que o valor fique o mesmo que eram na *string*: "19.30", pois vou usá-lo para fazer diversos cálculos com ele. Se puder  converter para moeda também serve desde que o formato seja o mesmo que recebo como `string`

Existe algum método para fazer esta conversão sem que o valor seja alterado?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você provavelmente está com problema de "cultura". O .NET pega a informação sobre a cultura que está sendo usada no computador. Ele "lê o ambiente" e faz as operações de acordo com as informações fornecidas pelo sistema operacional. Uma das forma para conseguir fazer a conversão é mandar executá-la sem considerar a cultura específica do ambiente. Ou seja, tornar a cultura invariante.

Você pode tentar *setar* um cultura invariante para toda a *thread*:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
```

[Documentação do `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.thread.currentculture?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Threading_Thread_CurrentCulture)

Ou pode setar a cultura em um *overload* de um método que faz a conversão e aceita esta configuração:

```
double.TryParse(valor, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out valorDouble)
```

[Documentação do `double.TryParse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Double_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Double__)

ou

```
Convert.ToDouble(valor, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

[Documentação do `Convert.ToDouble()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.todouble?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0#System_Convert_ToDouble_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_)

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Culture/Double.cs).

Nos últimos exemplos estou considerando que está usando um `using System.Globalization` para acessar a classe [`CultureInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-6.0).

Certamente há outras formas de fazer e algumas podem atender situações diferentes. É preciso entender bem o assunto. Ele não é tão simples quanto parece já mostrei onde pode começar.

Evidentemente você pode usar uma cultura específica se isto for necessária. Veja toda a classe `CultureInfo`.

Comment: Ok valeu pelas respostas mas vou usar essa  pois é bem fácil de usar. 
Convert.ToDouble(valor, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: Acredito que para seu caso é mesmo. Vou até melhorar algumas coisas (depois do jogo :) )

Answer (score 6):

***Assim:***

```
CultureInfo formato = null;
formato = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.Clone();
formato.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
formato.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ","; 

string x = "19.30";
System.Console.Write(Convert.ToDouble(x, formato));
```

*Exemplo:* [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/PQDPqH)

*Referência:*

- [Método Convert.ToDouble (String, IFormatProvider)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/9s9ak971%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- [Propriedade CultureInfo.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.currentculture%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

## [Thread.CurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.threading.thread.currentculture.aspx)

Como o pessoal disse, o método parse irá utilizar a cultura atual da thread para interpretar/formatar o valor.

Mudar a cultura atual da thread é só uma questão de alterar a propriedade *CurrentCulture* da thread atual:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture; // ou a cultura que desejar
```

---

## [CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture.aspx)

A partir do .NET 4.5 você pode definir uma cultura default para todas threads para sua aplicação (para seu [*application domain*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx) para ser mais específico. Pode ser muito útil se sua aplicação utiliza/cria várias threads.

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR");
```