# Problema ao inserir valor double no MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, string, query

```
query += txtServidor.Text + "',";<br>
query += double.Parse(txtVencimento.Text) + ",";<br>
query += int.Parse(txtBanco.Text) + ",'";<br>

INSERT INTO tbl_associados VALUES(10,'testando','001.318.555-55','categoria','ativo',
    'MG-13.131.313','2010-07-10','ssp/mg','1999-07-07',20,'2014-12-10','M','SI','Solteiro','',
    'pai teste','mae teste','(31)3333-3333','(33)9999-9999','(37)9999-8888','email teste',
    'Avenida teste',444,'','bairro','cidade','30421-888','MG','07 -Timóteo','setor','cargo',
    'dez/2010',10025,1044,'1234','4','013','S','S');
```

O valor "10025" na última linha deveria ser "100.25", o `txtVencimento.Text` recebeu o valor correto 100.25, porém ao *debugar* o código percebi que ao concatenar o valor com o restante da *query*, o ponto simplesmente foi ignorado (sozinho) e está indo como mostrei ali em cima na *query*.

No banco de dados o vencimento é do tipo `double(9,2) not null`.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: Remover o "Parse" pode resolver, já que a variável 'query' é string e você irá concatenar todos os valores como string. Não tem lógica converter pra double/int se será concatenado como string.

Answer (score 2):

Em primeiro lugar, você jura que está usando `double` para manipular valores monetários? Veja [essa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101). isto vale tanto para o código em C#, quanto para o banco de dados. Você vai causar problema financeiros e possivelmente fiscais, com implicações legais para empresa usuária deste software.

Alguma coisa me diz que outros tipos estão errados, como por exemplo este [`int` para o banco](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/47871/101). Mas não posso dizer muito sem ver o todo e não é o foco da pergunta. Só estou te alertando que o seu sistema tem outros sérios problemas e não podia deixar passar em branco.

Outro problema é que pode ser que o formato não venha correto e o *parse* pode falhar. Você vai deixar ocorrer um erro? Ou pior, aceitar um valor inadequado?

O seu problema provavelmente tem a ver com a cultura que está usando, mas não posso garantir porque falta informações na pergunta. Se for isto, pode ser que já foi [respondido aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/21293/101). Então uma possibilidade para resolver isto seria:

```
Decimal.TryParse(txtVencimento.Text, NumberStyles.Any,
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out valorDecimal)
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conversion/ParseCulture.cs).

Mas pode ser que a cultura necessária para o seu caso seria a `CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("pt-BR")`. Tem exemplo completo e explicação na [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.decimal.tryparse?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_Decimal_TryParse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_System_Decimal__). Se este estilo não for o mais adequado pode escolher outros de acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.numberstyles?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Não coloco mais detalhes porque a pergunta não ajuda.

Mas note que esta solução tenta resolver todos os problemas: muda o `double` para `decimal`, tenta fazer o *parse*, mas dá a chance de cuidar se ele falhar e usa cultura para manipular corretamente o ponto decimal.

Evidentemente se não quiser seguir minha recomendação de resolver todos os problemas, pode usar um [`double.Parse()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=net-5.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397#System_Double_Parse_System_String_System_Globalization_NumberStyles_System_IFormatProvider_) simples só com a cultura. Será um erro mas é sua opção.

Answer (score 0):

Tenta fazer o parse dessa forma:

```
double.Parse(txtVencimento.Text, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```